# SDL + Chipmunk CMake config

Tags: makefile, cmake, sdl, chipmunk

I want to link the [Chipmunk2D physics framework](https://github.com/slembcke/Chipmunk2D) with SDL via CMake.

I have the following project structure:

```
MyProject
    -chipmunk:
      --include
      --demo:
        ---CMakeList.txt
      --src:
       ---CMakeList.txt
      --CMakeList.txt
    -src:
      --main.cpp
    -CMakeLists.txt
```

I read about static and shared libraries, and decide I want to use a static library, so I went in the chipmunk folder and I ran ***cmake .***

1.The first CMakeList file sets the options:

```
  message(STATUS "Set BUILD_STATIC option ON")
  option(BUILD_SHARED "Build and install the shared library" ON)
  option(BUILD_STATIC "Build as static library" ON)
  option(INSTALL_STATIC "Install the static library" ON)
```

and after that:

```
add_subdirectory(src)
```

2. The CMakeList.txt from src enters the action:

   ```
   if(BUILD_STATIC)
   message(STATUS "BUILDING chipmunk_static")
   add_library(chipmunk_static STATIC ${chipmunk_source_files})
   set_target_properties(chipmunk_static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME chipmunk)
    if(INSTALL_STATIC)
      message(STATUS "INSTALL chipmunk_static ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}")
      install(TARGETS chipmunk_static ARCHIVE DESTINATION {LIB_INSTALL_DIR})
    endif(INSTALL_STATIC)
   endif(BUILD_STATIC)
   ```
3. In the demo folder the CmakeFile does the follows:

   ```
   set(chipmunk_demos_libraries
   chipmunk_static
   ${GLEW_LIBRARIES}
   ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
   )
   ```

S0 my questions are:

1. Do I need to run the Makefiles from the chipmunk libraries only once so I can build the static library?
2. After I included the CMakefile from chipmunk in my Cmakefile it seems it cannot found the static library (**I'm on Linux btw**)
3. If I have the static library built, can I delete all the src content from chipmunk and keep only the headers?

My attempt to find the chipmunk static library *without success*:

```
add_subdirectory(chipmunk)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_library(CHIPMUNK_LIB chipmunk_static)
message(${CHIPMUNK_LIB})
```

Comment: Several questions in the question post, and neither one is clear. `... it seems it cannot found the static library` - There are many information about linking external library in the net, including the questions on Stack Overflow. What exactly have you tried and what **exact error message** (or other error description) you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with CMake, when you "find" a library it looks for an installed one, not one built by a sub-project. So somewhere you should have a line where you reference the directory that has Chipmunk in it. In my project:

```
add_subdirectory(external/Chipmunk2D)
```

Then when you are building your executable (or library, whatever), you can just list libraries built by sub-projects by name. In my case, glfw, chipmunk_static, and enet are all built by CMake in sub-projects:

```
target_link_libraries(my_executable
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
    glfw
    chipmunk_static
    enet
)
```

Comment: Is there any reason to keep the sources in the project after you built the library?

Comment: @Gavriil, late answer, but whether you want to "keep the sources in the project after you built the library" depends on how you want to handle your dependencies. Based on slembcke's answer, it would seem like he advocates treating the Chipmunk2D sources files "as your own files", except that you don't have to write the CMakeList.txt file yourself for those, since it's already there. If you are using Git, you could for instance have Chipmunk2D as a submodule.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. For the record: it took me a while to understand that "chipmunk_static" was not some arbitrary name that only would apply to some particular project. Assuming the contents of the Chipmunk2D GitHub directory is present under a directory with the same name in one's source code tree, "chipmunk_static" is the CMake target name for the Chipmunk2D static library. This is why the simple `target_link_libraries` just works. In particular, there is no need for any `target_link_directories` for that to work